# google spreadsheet: no permission to access apps-scripts-editor, but I am owner

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a frustrating Script Editor problem, I'm sure I'm doing something simple wrong - would be glad for any advice!

I select script editor (from within google spreadsheets):

[image: Clicking on Script editor...]

Then I reach the permission denied error, suggesting I request access:
[image]

However, I am the owner of this spreadsheet, and I'm not receiving any permission emails:

[image]

So, any idea what's going on? I'm not receiving any emails after requesting permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being owner of the spreadsheet does not necessarily mean you are the owner of the script. Try to find out who is the owner of the script and ask them to share the script with you.

While you will be able to view and edit the script, you'll still not be able to do some priviledged tasks such as depoying as a webapp, managing versions.

Comment: That was it. I had to assign ownership of the spreadsheet back to the original author, who also wrote the scripts. Then he assigned both permissions back. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a couple of basic things that may cause issues...

Are you signed in to multiple accounts within the same browser? Some odd things can happen when multiple, enterprise and personal accounts are signed in at once.

I would clear your browsing data, ensure only one account is signed in and try again  :)

Comment: just logging out from my other google account did the trick (I was logged in with 2 accounts)

Comment: Thanks for that comment - it solved the problem I was having!